# How to show objects from an s3 bucket that is not public

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, security, amazon-s3, vue.js

I am trying to show objects from an S3 bucket that is not public. In order to do this I would have to provide the access and secret keys to AWS.

I have this fiddle (without the keys) but it does not work when I enter the correct keys: http://jsfiddle.net/jsp3wzbu/

```
<section ng-app data-ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <img  ng-src="{{s3url}}" id="myimg">
</section>
```

also, how is security handled? I would not want to store the access/secret keys in my client code because users will see it. My server code keeps these keys in environment variables and I fear that if I share them with my client side JS code, then they will be exposed. Is there any other way for me to show the S3 object on the browser? ....Can the server provide the images as base64 json and the client side code renders it?

Comment: You can use pre-signed URL: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html

Comment: For what time duration should I create the signed url? Is there a way to create a signed uri that is valid for only one get request?

Comment: You can choose any duration that you want. You can't create a signed url valid for only one request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I handle providing access to the contents of a private S3 bucket.

1. I use IAM roles for my EC2 instances. I do not store AWS credentials on the EC2 instance.
2. I require the user to login. You can use a home brew login setup (database), Cognito or another IDP such as Google or Facebook.
3. From my back-end code I generate presigned URLs that expire in 15 minutes. If the URLs are for large files, I adjust the timeout to be longer based upon the size of the file assuming a slow Internet connection.
4. In the JavaScript for my HTML pages, I refresh the URLs before the 15 minutes expires (usually every 5 minutes via AJAX). This can be done via a simple refresh page or (better) by using AJAX to just refresh the URLs. This handles users that leave a page open for a long period of time.

Comment: For point 3, your backend code is using I AM role to authenticate with aws and not access and secret keys? I use boto3 on backend to access AWS. I wonder if I can use IAM role instead

Comment: Correct, I am using an IAM role instead of IAM User Access Keys. This is the Amazon recommended method. The Boto3 library will automatically get the credentials from the IAM role provided you don't have the credentials stored elsewhere. The search order is Environment, Profile, then Role.

Comment: Ah so it just picks up the IAM role with which the EC2 instances was launched. The assumption is that the IAM role that was used to launch the instance would also have access to the S3 buckets the application needs access to

Comment: When you create the IAM role, you add / define the permissions that you want to the role. Then you assign the role to the EC2 instance.

Comment: Another alternative approach for Step 4 is to handle the OnClick event of the button/link from JavaScript and send a AJAX request to the server to generate a SignURL, where it is used to Download/Upload an object to S3.

Comment: @Ashan. Interesting idea for refreshing the presigned URL.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple approaches you can follow to achieve this.

- Use S3 Signed Urls.
- Use AWS STS to generate temporary access credentials from Backend.
- Use AWS Cognito Federated Identities to Generate temporary access credentials.
- Use CloudFront Signed Urls or Cookies.

Note: Storing or sending permanent IAM credentials to the client side is not recommended.